# ASP.NET Prevent login when EmailConfirmed is false using VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to add an if statement in the following code to deny users who haven't confirmed their email addresses - something like this pseudo code:

```
    if EmailConfirmed = false Then RedirectToURL and user = ""
```

in

```
    Protected Sub LogIn(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If IsValid Then

        ' Validate the user password
        Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
        Dim signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()


        ' This doen't count login failures towards account lockout
        ' To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout := True
        Dim result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout:=True)

        Select Case result
            Case SignInStatus.Success
                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"), Response)
                Exit Select
            Case SignInStatus.LockedOut
                Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout")
                Exit Select
            Case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification
                Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}",
                                            Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"),
                                            RememberMe.Checked),
                              True)
                Exit Select
            Case Else
                FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt"
                ErrorMessage.Visible = True
                Exit Select
        End Select

    End If
End Sub

   End Class
```

I've seen it done in C#, but I was unable to duplicate or convert it accurately.  Thank you for any help.

**UPDATE**

When I use the code there @HumbleBeginnings link and convert to VB I get:

```
 Dim user = Await.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email) 
 If user IsNot Nothing Then If Not 
 Await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id) Then 
 ViewBag.errorMessage = "You must have a confirmed email to log on." 
 Return    
 View("Error") 
End If
```

But is says that await can only be used with Async method, consider changing this method with Async modifier and changing it's return type to task

Comment: Can you please post .aspx code too? What control user have to check/teype to confirm email?

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel N.  Not sure which .aspx code to post.  I was able to get it working so that asp sends an email to user's email.  In the email is a link to confirm email.  When the user clicks the link a value is returned to my database to switch confirmedEmail from False to True.  Now I would like the user not to be able login if confirmedEmail = false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was how I ended solving this issue:

```
  Protected Async Sub LogIn(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If IsValid Then

        ' Validate the user password
        Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
        Dim signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()

        ' This doen't count login failures towards account lockout
        ' To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout := True
        Dim result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout:=True)

        Dim user = Await manager.FindByNameAsync(Email.Text)
        If user Is Nothing Then
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.")
        Else
        End If
        'Add this to check if the email was confirmed.
        If Not Await manager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id) Then
            ConfirmationExpected.Text = "Your email address has not been confirmed <br/> <br/>Please Check your email (including spam folder) <br/>OR Click 'Register' to have a new confirmation email generated."
            ConfirmationRequired.Visible = True

        Else

            Select Case result
                Case SignInStatus.Success
                    IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"), Response)
                    Exit Select
                Case SignInStatus.LockedOut
                    Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout")
                    Exit Select
                Case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification
                    Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}",
                                                    Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"),
                                                    RememberMe.Checked),
                                      True)
                    Exit Select
                Case Else
                    FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt"
                    ErrorMessage.Visible = True
                    Exit Select
            End Select

        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

This was the added code:

```
  Dim user = Await manager.FindByNameAsync(Email.Text)
    If user Is Nothing Then
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.")
    Else
    End If
    'Add this to check if the email was confirmed.
    If Not Await manager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id) Then
        ConfirmationExpected.Text = "Your email address has not been confirmed <br/> <br/>Please Check your email (including spam folder) <br/>OR Click 'Register' to have a new confirmation email generated."
        ConfirmationRequired.Visible = True

    Else
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [THIS](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset) link, specifically the part under the head "Require email confirmation before log in". There's a line commented out in the Account/Register Controller that seems to do the trick. It's in C# but it should get you close. Hope this helps.

Comment: PS HumbleBeginnings.  Interesting when I create my project in VB (probably a bad idea in hindsight), the code:   // Require the user to have a confirmed email before they can log on.
    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
    if (user != null)      
    {
       if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
       {
          ViewBag.errorMessage = "You must have a confirmed email to log on.";
          return View("Error");
       }
    }         is not there (like in the C# one.

Comment: The main thing about developing in VB is that most of your examples are in C# and need to be converted -- not always perfect. You are experiencing part of that problem. I have experienced a similar problem with converting (having nothing to do [at least yet!] with your problem) a function that implemented "IIdentityMessageService.SendAsync". The converter butchered it up pretty good. I spent too long assuming that the converter and intellisense had it right until I boned up on the subject and tried it my own way and it finally worked.

Comment: I'm willing to try to help but I think that you'll need to "perfect" your posting skills - at least so that you can get "code" to look like "code". Why don't you give it a practice shot (use the code link and read the instructions) and post again. You're bound to eliminate many helpful friends if they can't read your posts. I'm not the guru on either posting or this particular subject but I'll help if I can.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that you want to check if the email is confirmed BEFORE you attempt the sign in. Otherwise, they will be signed in when they go to a different page. Here's a change I made showing the order of logic. I redirect to a notvalidated page as well to keep the anti-XSRF problem at bay.

```
Protected Async Sub LogIn(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If IsValid Then
        Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
        Dim signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()

        Dim user = Await manager.FindByNameAsync(Email.Text)
        If user Is Nothing Then
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.")
            FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt"
            ErrorMessage.Visible = True
        Else
            'Add this to check if the email was confirmed. I check this before even attempting a login- as it logs the user in, regardless, if I do not.
            If Not Await manager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id) Then
                Response.Redirect("/Account/NotValidated")
            Else
                Dim result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout:=True)

                Select Case result
                    Case SignInStatus.Success
                        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"), Response)

                    Case SignInStatus.LockedOut
                        Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout")

                    Case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification
                        Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}",
                                                        Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"),
                                                        RememberMe.Checked),
                                          True)

                    Case Else
                        FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt"
                        ErrorMessage.Visible = True

                End Select
            End If
        End If

    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

to validate that the email has been confirmed you can solve by placing the following code in your loggin

```
 If IsValid Then
        ' Validate the user password
        Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
        Dim signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()

        ' este segmento valida que el usuario ya confirmo su cuenta de correo electronico, 
        ' de lo contrario no intenta ingresar
        ' you need add onli this code block -- init validate EmailConfirmed is false using VB.Net
        Dim user As ApplicationUser = manager.FindByName(Email.Text)
        If user Is Nothing OrElse Not manager.IsEmailConfirmed(user.Id) Then
            FailureText.Text = "El usuario no existe o bien no ha sido confirmado. <br/> Por favor confirmar su correo electrónico (Verifique la carpeta spam o correo no deseado). <br/> O Haga clic en 'Registrarse como nuevo usuario'"
            ErrorMessage.Visible = True
            Email.Focus()
            Return
        End If
        ' end validate EmailConfirmed is false using VB.Net

        ' This doen't count login failures towards account lockout
        ' To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout := True
        Dim result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout:=True)
        Select Case result
            Case SignInStatus.Success
                logger.Info(Email.Text & "│ usuario INICIO sesion ") ' comentario para la bitacora de logg
                System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Email.Text, True)
                'IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"), Response)
                Exit Select
            Case SignInStatus.LockedOut
                Response.Redirect("~/Account/Lockout")
                Exit Select
            Case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification
                Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}",
                                                Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"),
                                                RememberMe.Checked),
                                  True)
                Exit Select
            Case Else
                FailureText.Text = "Intento de inicio de sesión inválido "
                ErrorMessage.Visible = True
                Email.Focus()
                Exit Select
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```